# R count occurrences on a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I have a 4-dimensional array in R (lat, lon, time, variables) and I need to count for each variable the number of cases where the value is greater than x for each grid point (i.e.,  a lat-lon combination).
So the result should be a series of N maps (N = number of variables) (i.e., 2D array of lat-lon) with the values as integer counting the number of times the variable is greater than x.
The array dimensions are [60,185,8760,5].
I tried playing with tapply() but couldn't figure it out.

a reproducible example:

```
MyArray = array(rnorm(72), dim=c(3,4,2,3))
x = 0.7
which(MyArray[,,,1]>x)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks, Ilik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apply(MyArray,c(1,2,4),function(slice) sum(slice>x));
## , , 1
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    0    0    0
## [2,]    1    1    0    0
## [3,]    1    0    0    1
## 
## , , 2
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    1    0    0
## [2,]    0    1    1    0
## [3,]    1    0    0    0
## 
## , , 3
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    0    1    0
## [2,]    0    0    0    0
## [3,]    1    1    1    0
```